# Separate column into two: before and after a certain word

Tags: r

I have the following data set

```
> data
                                     firm_name
     1:                   Light Ltd John Smith
     2:            Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins
     3:     Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter
    ---
```

I want to separate it into two columns depending on the position of the "Ltd". So, the data would look like:

```
> data
                        firm_name             name
     1:                 Light Ltd       John Smith
     2:            Bolt Night Ltd     Mary Poppins
     3:     Bright Yellow Sun Ltd     Harry Potter
    ---
```

I tried with the `stringr` package but did not find any particular solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `separate` from `tidyr` with a lookbehind [regular expression](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) for this.

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(col = firm_name, into = c("firm_name", "name"), sep = "(?<=Ltd)")
#>               firm_name          name
#> 1             Light Ltd    John Smith
#> 2        Bolt Night Ltd  Mary Poppins
#> 3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd  Harry Potter
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(firm_name = c("Light Ltd John Smith",
                               "Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins",
                               "Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter"))
```

Comment: yes, this is precisely it. I did not consider the separate function knowing that it would omit the Ltd (still a rookie). But, with your trick it works. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?

```
df <- 
  tibble(
   names = c("Light Ltd John Smith",
            "Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins",
            "Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter")
  )
  

df %>% 
  tidyr::separate(names, c("half_1", "half_2"), sep = "Ltd")
```

Comment: in order to keep the "Ltd", the sep should be: sep = "(?<=Ltd)" as @JBGruber pointed out :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> df %>% mutate(name = gsub('([A-z].*Ltd) (.*)','\\2', df$firm_name), firm_name = gsub('([A-z].*Ltd) (.*)','\\1', df$firm_name))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  firm_name             name        
  <chr>                 <chr>       
1 Light Ltd             John Smith  
2 Bolt Night Ltd        Mary Poppins
3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter
>
```

Data used:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  firm_name                         
  <chr>                             
1 Light Ltd John Smith              
2 Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins       
3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr::extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, names, c('firm_name', 'name'), regex = '(.*Ltd)\\s(.*)')

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  firm_name             name        
#  <chr>                 <chr>       
#1 Light Ltd             John Smith  
#2 Bolt Night Ltd        Mary Poppins
#3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter
```

Or in base R :

```
df$name <- sub('.*Ltd\\s', '', df$names)
df$firm_name <- sub('(.*Ltd).*', '\\1', df$names)
df$names <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(Ltd)", "\\1,", df$names), 
         header = FALSE, col.names = c('firm_name', 'name'))
#            firm_name          name
#1             Light Ltd    John Smith
#2        Bolt Night Ltd  Mary Poppins
#3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd  Harry Potter
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("Light Ltd John Smith",
"Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins", 
"Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi arun, could you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582912/remove-yearly-values-when-month-or-quarters-are-missing

Comment: @user5249203 i just commented below your post

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
setNames(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      strsplit(df$names, "(?<=Ltd)\\s+", perl = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  c("firm_name", "name")
)
```

giving

```
              firm_name         name
1             Light Ltd   John Smith
2        Bolt Night Ltd Mary Poppins
3 Bright Yellow Sun Ltd Harry Potter
```