# remove yearly values when month or quarters are missing

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have monthly, quarterly, and yearly data for different ids. If for any month, the value is missing then depending on which quarter that month falls in, we need to flag that Quarter and the yearly value as well.

Similarly, when quarterly and yearly are reported, and if a quarter is missing. Then need to flag the yearly values.

In case where we have no monthly values are missing, then quarterly and yearly should NOT be flagged.

In below table filtered for id 1 ...

- Row 2 is Quarter 1 value. We retain this because, monthly value in that quarter is not missing.
- Row 6 is Quarter 2 value. It is flagged because, month 4 has missing value and month 4 belongs to quarter 2.
- similar case for row 10 (Q3) because month 7 & 8 are missing. Row 14 (Q4) because month 12 is missing
- Row 1 is year value. We flag it because overall in that year we have months with missing value

4. 

```
Example table: 
# A tibble: 17 x 6
      id value month quarter  year  flag
   <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1  1232    NA      NA  2017     1
 2     1    75    NA       1  2017     0
 3     1    26     1       1  2017     0
 4     1    29     2       1  2017     0
 5     1    20     3       1  2017     0
 6     1    93    NA       2  2017     1
 7     1    NA     4       2  2017     0
 8     1    33     5       2  2017     0
 9     1    35     6       2  2017     0
10     1    51    NA       3  2017     1
11     1    NA     7       3  2017     0
12     1    NA     8       3  2017     0
13     1     3     9       3  2017     0
14     1    55    NA       4  2017     1
15     1    15    10       4  2017     0
16     1    25    11       4  2017     0
17     1    NA    12       4  2017     0


dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), value = c(1232L, 75L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 
93L, NA, 33L, 35L, 51L, NA, NA, 3L, 55L, 15L, 25L, NA, 1232L, 
75L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 93L, 5L, 33L, 35L, 51L, 6L, NA, 3L, 55L, 
15L, 25L, NA, 1232L, 75L, 26L, 29L, NA, 5L, 33L, 35L, 6L, NA, 
3L, 15L, 25L, NA), month = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 
6L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
4L, 5L, 6L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), quarter = c(NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), year = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 217L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))
```

desired output

```
> dput(df_output)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), value = c(1232L, 75L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 
93L, NA, 33L, 35L, 51L, NA, NA, 3L, 55L, 15L, 25L, NA, 1232L, 
75L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 93L, 5L, 33L, 35L, 51L, 6L, NA, 3L, 55L, 
15L, 25L, NA, 1232L, 75L, 26L, 29L, NA, 5L, 33L, 35L, 6L, NA, 
3L, 15L, 25L, NA), month = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 
6L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
4L, 5L, 6L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), quarter = c(NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), year = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L), flag = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

This is what I have so far

```
df_output %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id,year) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(quarter_d = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(month) & !is.na(quarter) ~ paste("Q",quarter,year,sep="_"),
    )) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(quarter_flag = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(value) ~ paste("Q",ceiling(as.numeric(month) / 3),year,sep="_")
  ))
```

Comment: becasue, monthly data is not missing

Comment: yes, 93 is quarterly value. ( 2nd quarter). But, since all 3 months in that quarter are reported i.e months 4,5,6 months have no missing values (5,33,35). So we retain that quarter value.

Comment: sorry, I just changed the ids. copy pasted the values. If that is misleading, I can create another with different values.

Comment: also one of the year value is `217` may be a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223788/discussion-between-user5249203-and-akrun).

Comment: edited the Q with more explanation . Hope it helps.

Comment: @RonakShah "the first row of each quarter is flagged as 1 "...if any monthly value is missing for that quarter. The year value is flagged, because we have missing months in that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `NA` values first for each year and then for each quarter and assign 1 if any of those value is 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(year_flag = +(any(is.na(value)) & row_number() == 1)) %>%
  group_by(quarter, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(quarter_flag = +(any(is.na(value)) & row_number() == 1)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(flag = pmax(year_flag, quarter_flag))

#      id value month quarter  year year_flag quarter_flag  flag
#   <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int>     <int>        <int> <int>
# 1     1  1232    NA      NA  2017         1            0     1
# 2     1    75    NA       1  2017         0            0     0
# 3     1    26     1       1  2017         0            0     0
# 4     1    29     2       1  2017         0            0     0
# 5     1    20     3       1  2017         0            0     0
# 6     1    93    NA       2  2017         0            1     1
# 7     1    NA     4       2  2017         0            0     0
# 8     1    33     5       2  2017         0            0     0
# 9     1    35     6       2  2017         0            0     0
#10     1    51    NA       3  2017         0            1     1
# … with 38 more rows
```

I have kept additional columns `year_flag` and `quarter_flag` so that you understand what is going on. You can remove them from final output if not needed.

Comment: what is this doing  `+(any(is.na(value)) & row_number() == 1))` why you added + ?

Comment: That is to convert logical values to integer. So `TRUE` is changed to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

Comment: This is failing in a scenario where an id has all values in a month ( no missing values in month). Then we need to retain both quarterly and yearly. However, in the current form it is flagging yearly 1 even though we have all values in a month.

Comment: Do you have one such example for the data shared where a flag is falsely set to 1.

Comment: sorry, did not follow-up on the update. I guess it works currently, but will update the new data later. I have another Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756969/grouping-multiple-png-with-sub-headings-in-rmarkdown). Wondering if you have any inputs

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)
missing_months <- df %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  filter(!is.na(month), is.na(value)) %>% 
  select(-value)

missing_quarter <- df %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  filter(is.na(month), !is.na(quarter), is.na(value)) %>% 
  select(-value)

df_output <- df %>% 
  left_join(missing_months %>% mutate(month = NA_integer_) %>% distinct(id, month, quarter, year, flag.x = 1L), by = c("id", "month", "quarter", "year")) %>% 
  left_join(missing_months %>% mutate(month = NA_integer_, quarter = NA_integer_) %>% distinct(id, month, quarter, year, flag.y = 1L), by = c("id", "month", "quarter", "year")) %>% 
  left_join(missing_quarter %>% mutate(quarter = NA_integer_) %>% distinct(id, month, quarter, year, flag.z = 1L), by = c("id", "month", "quarter", "year")) %>% 
  mutate(flag = pmax(flag.x, flag.y, flag.z, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-flag.x, -flag.y, -flag.z) %>% 
  replace_na(list(flag = 0L))
```